# Does a choice function exist?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $I$ be some set of indexes. And for each $a \in I$: $X_a \subseteq \mathbb N \times \mathbb N$ and $X_a \neq \emptyset$. Find choice function, if it exists.

Any hints? How do you even show there is a choice function? Also, can a choice function not be injective?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Lexicographic order.

Comment: It may happen that the choice function *cannot* be injective. For example, if $A$ is a finite set with $n>1$ elements and we want a choice function for $\mathcal P(A)\setminus\{\emptyset\}$, which has $2^n-1>n$ elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a recurring theme in set theory: The sets in your example all come with a well-order. As a consequence you can define your choice function to be the function that chooses the smallest element in each set.

In general, with an arbitrary collection of non-empty sets you cannot do this because you can't specify the choice function. This is where the axiom of choice comes in: it lets you well-order the sets and as a consequence you can then get the same choice function as in this example.

Comment: Regarding "can a choice function not be injective" -- Yes, it can. Why do you think it can't?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Find a well-ordering of $\Bbb{N\times N}$, and recall that there is a canonical choice function from subsets of a well-ordered set.